# EasyApache only applies PHP7 to public_html?

Tags: php, laravel-5, easyapache-4

I'm using EasyApache 4 and Laravel 5.5 to deploy an API on a shared host. I got the project running at same level than `public_html`. In `public_html`, there's only project's `public_html` files. Now if I access my routes, they work fine. They where not, before, I was getting [this error](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-55-syntax-error-unexpected-in-vendorlaravelframeworksrcilluminatefoundationhelpersphp-on-line-233), which means it was not running on PHP7. So I fixed with EasyApache and run PHP 7 on that account.

**The problem**
If I access server trough ssh, cd to project's folder and run:

```
php artisan db:migrate
```

I got the same error again:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/someaccount/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233

And if I google, that's the cause: the project is running on PHP < 7. So that's my question: does EasyApache only applies PHP versions on `public_html` folder?

UPDATE: I got full access to WHM and SSH, is there a way to make PHP 7 default?

Comment: It may be quite complicated to change default PHP in console. However it could be enough to use `ea-php70` or something instead of `php`.

Comment: @Michas I did. My account is running with php7 and laravel codes are running fine. However, php artisan throw's this error wich means php7 is not installed ?!

Comment: Do You have this error if You type in console `ea-php70 artisan db:migrate` and `ea-php71 artisan db:migrate` ?

Comment: @Michas that's right! But not only ea-php70, I'll post full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
Call this /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php artisan db:migrate

Answer (score 1):

Go to root and create an .htaccess file with these lines in it:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

Then you can check in root from terminal to see result: php -v